# Close userform using myForm.Hide or Unload Me

Tags: vba, excel, memory, userform

Before I start let me give you the background. I am working on a VBA project with Excel and the computer I am using has limited resources (and I have been asked to do as light as possible for fast execution time). 
In my project I open multiple userform at different times, to apply filters on my sheet for example.

As I just said resources are limited and I want to know if `frmFilters.Hide` is enough to close the userform or if there is a better way to do so ?

[I've read about](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/336931-unload-vs-hide.html) `Unload Me` but I'm not sure how it's working because I'll apply filters from my form and I need to keep them once the form is closed until the user totally close the Excel file.

Is there a situation where `Unload Me` is better than `frmFilters.Hide` ?

Regards,
Teasel

Comment: If you need to keep your filters, it would be better to save them in an INI file of some sort.

Comment: @braX Sorry I haven't been precise enough. I don't need to keep the filters forever but only until the user close the Excel file (I edited my post). My question is more about how to manage the form than how to manage filters.

Comment: In that case, just hiding the form is good enough.

Comment: If you use multiple forms it is better to use `Unload Me` because, as far as I remember, with use of `UserForm.Hide` project persists in Run mode which can lead to unpredictable circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting answer to my question I thought it would be useful to post it here.

**Unload me**

```
Unload me
```

Removes the form from the memory and stop the application if you do so on the main form of your project. Every modification that you did in your form will be lost.

**Hide**

```
myForm.Hide
```

Only hide the form. If you do so on the main form of your application, this will not end the program (the debug mode would still be running for example). Every modification that you do in your form will be kept for the next time you show your form.

**Which one to use?**

Depends of the situation I believe. In my project, my form was made to be open/close multiple times so I chose to only hide it to avoid having to allow memory for my form every time.

Comment: Consider reading [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) where you might get some ideas why one should avoid `Unload Me` :-)