# How to close form without closing the whole Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a Form in excel 2017 with a "Cancel" button, but I don't know how to code it so that it closes itself when clicked. I've found things like "Application.Quit" but it closes everything.

Comment: use `Unload Me` to close only the `Userform`

Comment: @ShaiRado post this as an answer

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda i posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that. Both will only close your form and keep Excel opened.

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838982/close-userform-using-myform-hide-or-unload-me) about it a while ago maybe this can help you.

---

**1. Hide Method**

Your userForm has a `Hide` method, you can call it to hide your form.

Example:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    yourFormName.Hide
End Sub
```

Using the Hide method will only hide the form, it will be totally closed when you close your Excel file.

If you make changes in the form, hide it and then show it again all changes will be kept (ex: change the value of a textbox before hiding it and it will stay the next time you show your form).

The **Activate** event won't be triggered next time you show the form since the form was still active but hidden.

---

**2. Unload Method**

You can call the `Unload` method to unload your form.

Example:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    Unload me
End Sub
```

The form is unloaded from the memory. If you make changes in your form and then unload it, it won't be kept next time you show your form unlike with the Hide method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Unload Me` to close the `Userform`.