# If then else condition with defined range and msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with a defined named range (a list of items, let's say apple, orange, banana etc - this range is called [Liste] in the below code) in Sheet 1.

In sheet 2 I have several cells (B7:B26) that when you click on them, a userform appears and you can search and select items from Sheet 1. All that works great. However, you are also able to mistype words and enter it without receiving an error (and therefore, the value in the cell won't match any of the items from the list in Sheet 1). Therefore, I thought it would be nice if I could have a msgbox appear with an error message, then clear the content of the cell so the person can start over. I have looked everywhere and tried a couple of codes but couldn't find one where a cell is matched to a named range (list).

Here a quick recap of what I would like the code to do:

- If value entered in the userform for the selected cell does NOT match any of the items in the list from Sheet 1, a msgbox appears saying "Wrong name entered. Please try again" with an ok button
- Once you click ok it should also clear the content of the selected cell
- If possible (that would be an amazing add on), reopen the userform so they can start over

I have tried variation of codes already including establishing Dim for each item first, a for loop, etc but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code I have in my sheet that opens the UseForm (for background info - this works perfectly):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect([B7:B26], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
  With UserForm4
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

Code for the userform (also works perfectly):

```
Dim a()

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  a = [Liste].Value
  Me.ComboBox1.List = a
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  tmp = UCase(Me.ComboBox1) & "*"
  For Each c In a
    If UCase(c) Like tmp Then d1(c) = ""
  Next c
  Me.ComboBox1.List = d1.keys
  Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1
  Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1: Unload Me
End Sub
```

Code I added to Sheet 2 (where I would like the msgbox to appear; found it from another post that I thought was similar enough):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim vFindvar As Variant

Set rSearchRng = Range([Liste])
Set vFindvar = rSearchRng.Find(Range("B7:B26").Value)
If Not vFindvar Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The Audit Project Name you have entered is not valid. Please try again!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
    Selection.ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

At the moment I get error '1004' (Method range of object_worksheet failed) for the `Set rSearchrng = range([Liste])` line.

I am open to totally new code if you have a better way of getting to to the results I would like to see (I am also not sure if I should put this code in the userform or the actual sheet itself where the output is?)

Thank you in advance for you help!
V

**UPDATE**

Since I have posted this, I have edited my code to look like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim vFindvar As Variant

If Not Intersect([B7:B26], Target) Is Nothing Then
    Set rSearchRng = Sheet4.Range("Liste")
    Set vFindvar = rSearchRng.Find(Target.Value)
    If Not vFindvar Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Audit Project Name you have entered is not valid. Please try again!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`
```

However, this only partly solved my issue. It works perfectly with some letters but not others. For example, if I type "ad" (not in the list) it works perfectly but if I put "ate" or "be" (not in the list) it does not show the error msgbox and just lets me enter the invalid input.

*Does anyone have any idea why it only works partially?*

Comment: You need to specify the `Worksheet` the `Range` is on. Try `Set rSearchRng = Sheet1.Range("Liste")`.

Comment: Okay now it works, the msgbox pops up and the content is cleared. However, since an empty cell isn't in the predefined list of items, the msgbox just keeps on reappearing. How can I add a code that makes sure blank cells are ignored?

Comment: Sorry, I made it work in the end but you were too fast. However, now the msgbox just keeps on reappearing because of the blank cell (see message above)? is there something I could add to the code to ignore blank cells?

Comment: You need to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of `Sub Worksheet_Change...`, and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Last thing (not sure if possible), could I make the userform box reappear after they click "OK" and the cell is cleared? I tried adding UserForm4.show at the end of this sub but it gives me an error saying the form is already opened.

Comment: What's the exact error message? By the way, instead of using `Unload Me` you can use `Me.Hide`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838982/close-userform-using-myform-hide-or-unload-me) for more detail.

Comment: I get error "400" (Form already displayed; can't show modally). I changed it to `Me.Hide` hoping that would solve my error problem but it still pops up. Also, the msgbox now also pops up when I enter something correctly (that is definitely in the list of Sheet1). Why is this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/form-already-displayed-can-t-show-modally-error-400

Comment: I'm not sure you want `Range("B7:B26").Value`. I think you need to look at using `Target`, first checking whether `Target` is in `B7:B26` (?) using `Intersect`.

Comment: I tried adding intersect instead but now nothing seems to work (the userform doesn't even pop up). This is what I had:

Comment: `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim rSearchRng As Range
Dim vFindvar As Variant

If Not Intersect([B7:B26], Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
    Set rSearchRng = Sheet4.Range("Liste")
    Set vFindvar = rSearchRng.Find(Target.Value)
If Not vFindvar Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Bla", vbExclamation, "Error!"
    Selection.ClearContents
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`

Comment: Okay so the code seems to work now (and let me put in valid selections). The only thing that still gives me an error is my `UserForm4.Show` at the end (same 400 code) even though I changed all `Unload Me` to `Me.Hide`

Comment: Weird thing, it gives me the error message on some letters/words but not all. For example if I type "ad" (not in the list), the msgbox pops up correctly. If I type "ate" (not in the list) it lets me enter it without the error msgbox. Any idea?

Comment: Apparently you want `Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)`. However it looks to me like you are trying to reinvent [Excel validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249).

Comment: @GSerg I tried applying data validation to it (to show an error message) but I couldn't make it work. I tried both "list" and "custom" with a formula that I found online (which apparently worked for others) but the error message just wouldn't show up. If you know a way to do this with data validation, I am more than happy to see it! :) For some reason (after closing and reopening the file), the msgbox doesn't appear anymore..