# Hidden UserForm apprears when hovering over Excel app

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm developing a tool for my company using Excel VBA. In this tool I need UserForms. I noticed that when i hide them (usually when the user clicks "Ok", the code processes the info I need and there's a line somewhere saying Me.Hide), they still appear when I hover the mouse on the Excel app in the taskbar, when another app is on top.

The userform does disappear when I click on Excel.

I also noticed that the data the user entered is still there when I open the userform again. I don't know if these issues are related.

(The question is of course how to have the userform not appear and how to reset the fields)

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you are working on in your question and explain the problem you are having with it.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838982/close-userform-using-myform-hide-or-unload-me/46068369)

Comment: Teasel's answer helped me: using Unload Me instead of Me.Hide

Answer (score 0):

I used Unload Me instead of Me.Hide and it worked perfectly